# Efficient way to get data from an array of non primary-key IDs?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

I have a Ruby/Sinatra app, in which I am receiving and parsing a JSON string of images such as:

```
[{"id" => "ABCD123", "type" => "image"},
 {"id" => "ABCD234", "type" => "image"},
 {"id" => "ABCD345", "type" => "image"},
 {"id" => "ABCD456", "type" => "image"},
 {"id" => "ABCD567", "type" => "image"}]
```

In the database, I have a number of rows that store captions for the images. Currently, I have a function that iterates over the array and does the following:

app.rb

```
def get_caption(image_id)
  caption = Images.find_by_image_id image_id
end
```

index.haml

```
-images.each do |image|
  %div= get_caption(image['id'])
```

This seems very inefficient because the site does a unique lookup per image which definitely seems to be adding up in the load time of the page.

```
Images Load (131.6ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"  WHERE "images"."image_id" = 'ABCD123' LIMIT 1
...
Images Load (131.6ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"  WHERE "images"."image_id" = 'ABCD567' LIMIT 1
```

`131.6ms * n` queries really adds up quickly (I'm hoping that this slow ~130ms lookup will be improved by the time we optimize for production as well, but maybe this will be another question for later!).

Is there any more efficient way to do this lookup? Something along the lines of joining the `caption` field into the array somehow?

Comment: instead of running a whack of separate queries, a `where in (x,y,z,....)` type construct would probably help. and having indexes on the image_id field would help as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do to optimize this:

1. Fetch all required data from the database at once instead of in a loop:

   ```
   Images.where(image_id: image_ids).index_by(&:image_id)
   ```
2. Create a secondary index on the `image_id` column in the database:

   ```
   add_index :images, :image_id
   ```

A couple of other things I would like to highlight that go against the convention of Rails:

1. A model's name must be singular and the table name must be plural. That means the model's name should be `Image`.
2. I may be wrong but it looks like the query is being made in the view or a helper. All database queries should be in models, except the "find by primary key" which can be in the controller.

Comment: All good advice. The secondary index on the `image_id` column could be good if images have unique IDs beyond the normal row ID. I'd probably rely on the row ID as the unique identifier and code around that, but that's just me. And I'd probably later find some reason why I didn't like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write as

```
def get_captions(image_ids)
  caption = Images.where(image_id: image_ids)
end

image_ids = images.map { |image| image['id'] }
get_captions(image_ids)
```